# Why does a report throw an error when the corresponding query doesn't?

Tags: ms-access

I have to use a Microsoft Access application. (At least until I've got time to rewrite it in another language.)

I've got a report that throws the error "Syntax error in PARAMETER clause."

At the moment the SQL looks like this:

```
PARAMETERS [Test] Text ( 255 );
SELECT …
```

If I remove the PARAMETERS-line the problem vanishes.

Strange is, that if I open the query in the Datasheet view, the program displays the dialog. Only if I try to open the report it displays this message.

Any clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be a bug that's fixed by MS Office Service Pack 1?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942378

About a third the way down that document:

*Error message when you execute a query that contains parameters in Access 2007: "Syntax error in Parameter clause"
In Access 2007, you receive the following error message when you try to execute a query that contains parameters:*

Comment: I'm installing it now. I thought I'd updated my conputer, but it turned out that all non-system updates weren't installed. Thanks.